# Jenkins trigger job by another which are running on offline node

Tags: plugins, jenkins, nodes

Is there any way to do the following:

I have 2 jobs. One job on offline node has to trigger the second one. Are there any plugins in Jenkins that can do this. I know that TeamCity has a way of achieving this, but I think that Jenkins is more constrictive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure your node, you can set **Availability** to `Take this slave on-line when in demand and off-line when idle`.

Set **Usage** as `Leave this machine for tied jobs only`

Finally, configure the job to be executed only on that node.

This way, when the job goes to queue and cannot execute (because the node is offline), Jenkins will try to bring this node online. After the job is finished, the node will go back to offline.

This of course relies on the fact that Jenkins is configured to be able to start this node.

Answer (score 0):

One instance will always be turn on, on which the main job can be run. And have created the job which will look in DB and if in the DB no running instances, it will prepare one node. And the third job after running tests will clean up my environment.